# How to convert my data in R

Tags: r

I have a data which has the format like this , in order to be able to visualise the data I need to change the formatting to something like the second example, do you know how I can change the formatting like that ?

```
The first row is Age range
0–14    15–24   25–34   35–44   45–54   55–64   65 years and over   
1,873.4 1,088.4 1,296.4 1,157.2 1,207.5 1,177.5 1,498.7 
513.0   351.8   339.1   419.1   485.0   624.1   925.7   
1,049.9 666.4   594.2   682.9   645.7   650.2   727.1   
422.6   287.7   354.1   344.9   400.6   411.5   528.3   
2,069.1 1,234.7 1,429.0 1,310.3 1,323.1 1,229.6 1,514.9 
178.0   306.8   253.8   248.9   178.5   75.2    42.1    
2,247.2 1,541.5 1,682.9 1,559.2 1,501.5 1,304.8 1,557.0
```

How I can convert my data to look like this:

```
Age     Count
0-14    1,873.4
15-24   1,088.4
25-34   1,296.4
35-44   1,157.2
45-54   1,207.5
55-64   1,177.5
65+     1,498.7
0-14    513.0
15-24   351.8
25-34   339.1
35-44   419.1
45-54   485.0
55-64   624.1
65+     925.7
0-14    1,049.0
15-24   666.4
25-34   594.2
35-44   682.9
45-54   645.7
55-64   650.2
65+     727.1
0-14    422.6
15-24   287.7
25-34   354.1
35-44   344.9
45-54   400.6
55-64   411.5
65+     528.3
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to share the data you have - right now it's structure is unclear. Just paste `dput(your_data)` into the question.

Comment: Is this character `1,873.4`?

Answer (score 0):

I would alos use `reshape2::melt` but differently.
First the data, in `dput` format.

```
Tamra <-
structure(list(`0–14` = c("1,873.4", "513.0", "1,049.9", "422.6", 
"2,069.1", "178.0", "2,247.2"), `15–24` = c("1,088.4", "351.8", 
"666.4", "287.7", "1,234.7", "306.8", "1,541.5"), `25–34` = c("1,296.4", 
"339.1", "594.2", "354.1", "1,429.0", "253.8", "1,682.9"), `35–44` = c("1,157.2", 
"419.1", "682.9", "344.9", "1,310.3", "248.9", "1,559.2"), `45–54` = c("1,207.5", 
"485.0", "645.7", "400.6", "1,323.1", "178.5", "1,501.5"), `55–64` = c("1,177.5", 
"624.1", "650.2", "411.5", "1,229.6", "75.2", "1,304.8"), `65+` = c("1,498.7", 
"925.7", "727.1", "528.3", "1,514.9", "42.1", "1,557.0")), .Names = c("0–14", 
"15–24", "25–34", "35–44", "45–54", "55–64", "65+"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Now the code.

```
molten <- reshape2::melt(Tamra, measure.vars = names(Tamra),
                         variable.name = "Age", value.name = "Count")
#head(molten)
#   Age   Count
#1 0–14 1,873.4
#2 0–14   513.0
#3 0–14 1,049.9
#4 0–14   422.6
#5 0–14 2,069.1
#6 0–14   178.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `dplyr` + `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  gather(AgeRange, count) %>%
  mutate(count = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", count))) %>%
  arrange(rep(1:nrow(df), ncol(df)))
```

**Result:**

```
   AgeRange  count
1      0–14 1873.4
2     15–24 1088.4
3     25–34 1296.4
4     35–44 1157.2
5     45–54 1207.5
6     55–64 1177.5
7       65+ 1498.7
8      0–14  513.0
9     15–24  351.8
10    25–34  339.1
11    35–44  419.1
12    45–54  485.0
13    55–64  624.1
14      65+  925.7
15     0–14 1049.9
16    15–24  666.4
17    25–34  594.2
18    35–44  682.9
19    45–54  645.7
20    55–64  650.2
 ...
```

**Note:**

I've also added `mutate` step to convert the `counts` column to `numeric`

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(`0–14` = c("1,873.4", "513.0", "1,049.9", "422.6", 
"2,069.1", "178.0", "2,247.2"), `15–24` = c("1,088.4", "351.8", 
"666.4", "287.7", "1,234.7", "306.8", "1,541.5"), `25–34` = c("1,296.4", 
"339.1", "594.2", "354.1", "1,429.0", "253.8", "1,682.9"), `35–44` = c("1,157.2", 
"419.1", "682.9", "344.9", "1,310.3", "248.9", "1,559.2"), `45–54` = c("1,207.5", 
"485.0", "645.7", "400.6", "1,323.1", "178.5", "1,501.5"), `55–64` = c("1,177.5", 
"624.1", "650.2", "411.5", "1,229.6", "75.2", "1,304.8"), `65+` = c("1,498.7", 
"925.7", "727.1", "528.3", "1,514.9", "42.1", "1,557.0")), .Names = c("0–14", 
"15–24", "25–34", "35–44", "45–54", "55–64", "65+"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score -1):

If your table is named `tab`, I would do:

```
# Load library
  library(reshape)

# Use melt() function
  melt.tab <- melt(tab)
```

What you are looking for is the second and third row of `melt.tab`; that is:

```
 melt.tab[,-1]
```